# Akka Cluster Leader Address

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

How do I get a reference to the Leader in a Akka cluster so that I can send a message to the leader node ?

in code :

```
// assume there exists /user/Supervisor actor at the leader node
val leader = { code to get the leader ref }
leader ! SomeMessage
```

Comment: `context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://SysName@localhost:port/user/Supervisor").resolveOne` ??

Comment: @johny that won't work. since the address( SysName@localhost:port) of the leader node is not known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get its address from `Cluster(system).state.leader` or listen for the `LeaderChanged` cluster domain event to get notified when it changes.